# Sorting Vector elements

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

How can i sort a vectors element from ith index to jth index using sort() function.suppose i have a vector,and its elements are {3,1,2,4,5,7,6,10,9}.I want to sort from i'th index to j'th index.I have done this:

```
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<int>vc;
    vc.push_back(10);
    vc.push_back(9);
    vc.push_back(8);
    vc.push_back(7);
    vc.push_back(6);
    vc.push_back(5);
    vc.push_back(4);
    vc.push_back(3);
    vc.push_back(2);
    sort(vc.begin()+2,vc.begin()+6);
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
    cout<<vc[i]<<" ";
}
```

But it was not sorting.I only want to sort the middle elements.How can i do that?

Comment: What does '*not working*' mean? What went wrong?

Comment: When you say it's not working, what result are you seeing and what is the desired result? Your code should work.

Comment: Don't program by random guessing. Learn. Think. Know. `<bits/stdc++.h>` isn't a valid header for you.

Comment: [`std::sort()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) says [`#include <algorithm>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm).

Comment: what's with `#include<bits/stdc++.h>`?

Comment: You're sorting the elements `{4,5,7}` and they're already ordered.

Comment: i said that the elements are not sorting.

Comment: @user3700648 You did **not** say they weren't sorting. You said that 'it was not working.' Please post the updated code in your question so we don't have to attempt to read that.

Comment: but if you try sort(vc.begin()+2,vc.begin()+6),that is not sorting.

Comment: @user3700648: The code you've posted does exactly what you told it to do. [Live demo on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/bN08Cv)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A simple bubble sort implementation. That you can use to sort instead of using 
std::sort. Although this is slower this algorithm is `O(n^2)`

NOTE: THIS DOES NO ERROR CHECKING THIS IS ASSUMING PERFECT INPUT

```
 void sortMid(vector<int> &vec, int s, int e){

    int temp;
    for(int i = s; i < e; i++){
      for(int j = s; j<e; j++){
        if(vec[s+1] > vec[j]){
           temp = vec[j];
           vec[j]=vec[j+1];
           vec[j+1] = temp;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Isn,t it can be done by using sort function?

Comment: @user3700648 As stated by others your issue is that the elements you're trying to sort are already sorted. Change your code to `std::sort(vc.begin() + 2, vc.begin() + 7)`.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you're confused about the `end` parameter to `sort`. It's not the last element of the sequence, it's *one past* the last element. Therefore you're trying to sort elements 3, 4, and 5, which are already sorted - you won't see any change.

Comment: if i want sort elements 4,5 and 6 using sort function what i have to do?

Comment: @user3700648: You need to be more clear. Do you want to sort the values `4,5,6` or the vector indexes 4 through 6?

Comment: i want to sort vector indexes 4 to 6

Comment: @user3700648: Standard library algorithms take a _half-open_ iterator range of the `first` element and `one past the last` element. The range that includes indexes `[4, 6]` is actually `[4, 7)` so you need to use `begin()+4` and `begin()+7`.